# Centos 6.6 : Which java is selected when I run a JAR/WAR file without using java -jar command?

Tags: linux, java, centos6

On a Centos 6.6 server, how can I choose which java should be selected when I run an executable JAR or WAR file without using the "java -jar" command. I mean, I'd like to execute it with a "./archive.war" command.

On this server, I have java6, java7 and java8 installed. PATH and JAVA_HOME for user root points to the java8 (everything is done with root). The executable WAR I want to execute requires to be run with java8.

When I run my executable WAR with the "java -jar" command, everything works ok. The java version that is selected is correct.

```
[...]# java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

But, when I try to run this war using the following command ...

```
./archive.war
```

I get a java version error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: <CLASS HERE!> : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Meaning that Centos has not selected the expected java8 version. The PATH and JAVA_HOME variables for user root have not been taken into account?

I think I miss something that would indicate to the system which executable must be used when trying to execute a file with *.WAR/JAR file extension? At the moment, this must be pointing to java6 or java7, instead of java8.

Comment: Probably in the WAR file itself.

Comment: Why is this on hold? It's perfectly clear what jps wants! The desired end state is: `./archive.war` gives no exception. Any Linux/UNIX sysadmin worth his salt should understand the issue here. The error is given: the exception message. He's given information about PATH and JAVA_HOME, and he's told us it's on CentOS6.6 and that he has a bunch of Java's installed. What's left? The answer? If he knew that he wouldn't be using ServerFault! I don't get the on hold at all.  (All that said, I don't know the answer. But I find it unnerving: the poor guy is sweating but he got put on hold...)

Answer (score 1):

As a root user, you can append the JAVA_HOME value in /etc/profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdkpath
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/opt/jdkpath/bin
```

Change /opt/jdkpath to the correct path of your jdk installation.

Once you do that you can logout & login back & execute the service command

Comment: done - but still the same error ..

Comment: You need to make sure that your java version is correct. What do you get if you execute "java -version" ?. Verify that it's the correct version your application is expecting

Comment: Also you need to make sure that you have installed the correct java version (minor version) which your application requires

Comment: Java version is correct (java -version > java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode) . When I run "java -jar archive.war", everything's fine, tomcat starts normally ...